# Closing the modal by clicking anywhere else outside of it

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, popup

I'd like to close the modal by clicking anywhere else outside of it but don't really know how to put the functionality together. Ideally I'd like to have a pure JS or AngularJS solution. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/)

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in angular by adding click handlers to both the inner modal content and the outer div. In the inner div, you will need to stop event propagation by using `$event.stopPropagation`, otherwise the outer click handler will be called too. Then, when the outerDiv click handler is called, you can use angular's `$location` service to close the modal. See the attached plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/a3b5fU9G6wuXLLhiyI2D

Comment: thanks !, but why this does not work ?:/ I mean modal doest't want to turn on. In url is something like that: http://localhost:3000/#!#openModal and modal dont want open himself

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it would be like this:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
    var modal = $(this).find('.modal');
    if (!modal.is(e.target) && modal.has(e.target).length == 0) {
        modal.removeClass('opened');
    }
});
```

By the way it's better to set the visibility property to "hidden" when the modal is closed instead of disabling pointer-events. That way the user won't be able to click it either.